# Correlated subquery in BigQuery not possible

Tags: google-bigquery, correlated-subquery

I have a table that records the daily increase (new subs) and decrease (expired subs) of subscriptions. I would like to have the number of active subscribers on a particular day for every date recorded in the table.

I tried to create a query that calculates the sum of new sub minus the sum of expired subs of all the days before the day I want to see but it is not working on Big Query. A JOIN is not possible since I dont want t1.dates = t2.dates ofc.

```
SELECT t1.dates, 
(select sum(t2.new_subscriptions) - sum(t2.expired_subscriptions) from `daily_subscriber_change` t2 where t1.dates >= t2.dates) as active_abo 
from `daily_subscriber_change` t1
```

Any insight?

Comment: Please share some sample data in table format and desired result in table format. This will help to understand the problem clearly.

Comment: @Mohammad the table just has 3 columns: date (DATE), new_sub (INT) and expired_sub (INT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... to create a query that calculates the sum of new sub minus the sum of expired subs of all the days before the day I want to see

Consider below simple option (which is just exact "translation" of above)

```
select *, 
  sum(new_subscriptions - expired_subscriptions) over(order by dates)
from daily_subscriber_change
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have below ***daily_subscriber_change*** table. which has daily entry like below.

[image]

Now, you are looking for , as on ***Each Date*** what's the ***Active_Subscriptions*** so far. starting from day 1. Cumulative value as of date.

***Result***: It will take care even if you have multiple entries for any of the date.

[image]

To achieve this: you can write query like this:

```
with daily_subscriber_change as ( 
select date('2022-07-27') as dates, 5 as new_subscriptions, 3 as expired_subscriptions union all
select date('2022-07-26'), 7,4 union all
select date('2022-07-25'), 6,2 union all
select date('2022-07-24'), 1,0 union all
select date('2022-07-23'), 3,1 union all
select date('2022-07-22'), 1,4 union all
select date('2022-07-21'), 8,3 union all
select date('2022-07-20'), 1,4
)


SELECT T2.dates,T2.new_subscriptions,T2.expired_subscriptions,
  (SELECT SUM(new_subscriptions)-SUM(expired_subscriptions) 
  FROM daily_subscriber_change where dates <= safe_cast(T2.dates AS date))
   Active_Subscriptions
FROM daily_subscriber_change T2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, it is not quite what I wanted to build, as I would like a table with the active subs on all recorded days and not just the latest day. So for example, active sub on the 26/07 would be sum(new subs) - sum(expired subs) from 25th going downward. I hope I explained myself well..

Comment: Modified the answer based on the new input. Please have a look.

Comment: I tried it out on BigQuery, but got the same error. I think your code is pretty similar to my previous. The error is: "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN."